# Updating User causes error Target class [UserController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am having trouble when updating a user in the database/page. There was an error if I clicked the Edit button on the index page. The error is: **Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
The target class [UserController] does not exist.** Would you know how to update a specific user using Laravel 8? Thank you

**User Route**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::group(['prefix' => '/users',  'middleware' => 'user'], function() use ($router)
{
Route::get('', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');
Route::get('/{id}/edit',[UserController::class, 'edit'])->name('users.edit');
Route::put('/{id}/update',[UserController::class, 'update'])->name('users.update');
Route::get('/{id}/view',[UserController::class, 'show'])->name('users.show');
Route::get('/{id}/delete',[UserController::class, 'destroy'])->name('users.destroy');
});
```

**User Validator Middleware**

```
class UserValidator
{
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    
    if (request()->routeIs('users.update')){
        $this->validateUpdate($request);
    }

    return $next($request);
}

public function validateUser (Request $request, $id){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string|min:3|unique:books,name,'.$id,
        'description' => 'required|string|min:3',
     ]);
}


}
```

**User Controller**

```
public function edit($id){
    $users = User::all()->find($id);
    return view('users.edit')->with('users',$users);
 }

 public function update(Request $request,$id){
    User::whereId($id)->update($validated);
    return redirect()->route('users.index')
                    ->with('success','User updated successfully');
 }
```

**User Index Page**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)
       <tr>
          <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
          
          <td>
             <!-- Edit -->
             <a href="{{ route('users.show',$user->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Show</a>
             <!-- Edit -->
             <a href="{{ route('users.edit',$user->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Edit</a>
             <!-- Delete -->
             <a href="{{ route('users.destroy',$user->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?')">Delete</a>

          </td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

**User Edit Page**

```
<form action="{{route('users.update',[$users->id])}}" method="post" >
@csrf

   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-12 col-xs-12" name="name" placeholder="Enter student name" required="required" type="text" value="{{old('name',$users->name)}}">
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input id="email" class="form-control col-md-12 col-xs-12" name="email" placeholder="Enter student name" required="required" type="text" value="{{old('email',$users->email)}}">
     </div>
   </div>


   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value='Submit' class='btn btn-success'>
      </div>
   </div>

 </form>
```

Comment: In your routes file. Do you have `use App\Http\Controllers\UserController` at the top?

Comment: @aceraven777 yes, there is 'use App\Http\Controllers\UserController' at the top of the route file

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the whole content of the routes file? I am failing to see where's the problem.

Comment: @aceraven777 already edited the routes file. Thank you

Comment: I find it weird the index page is loading but the edit page is not. Maybe your routes are cached. Can you try running `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: It will be nice if in future you use ```Route::put('update/{id}',...``` instead of ```Route::put('/{id}/update',...```

Comment: Can you please shere your Controller shreenshot. You need to check that if name of controller class is same as importing in routs or not.

Comment: If you have recently created or moved the UserController file, it's possible that the class autoloading is not up to date. Run the following command in your terminal to regenerate the composer autoload files:

`composer dump-autoload`

Comment: did you edited any of these filename of controller,classname or copy pasted controller from any other folders?

Comment: I have different error when I use this 'php artisan route:clear'. The error: 'The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.'

Comment: @kimski POST is for creating a user. Don't you have that? Update is with PUT/PATCH.